# Why is the field of view angle from exiftool different from Apple's official values?

Tags: metadata, field-of-view, iphone, smartphone, exiftool

I have two series of photos shot on my iphone 6s on 10.3.2. The first series is in the regular frame, and the second series is in the "square" frame. I'm using exiftool 11.01 on macOS 10.11.6.

From the command line, when I run `exiftool -a -G0:1` on photos from the first series, I get:

`[Composite]     Field Of View                   : 63.7 deg`

And when I run the same on the second series, I get:

`[Composite]     Field Of View                   : 49.6 deg`

Both of these reported values differ significantly from all of Apple's official technical specs for the camera, [seen here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW22).

Can someone please clarify the discrepancy, and indicate which FOV value I should use when asked for the "angular field of view," i.e., the total opening angle of the camera lens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the linked tables, FOV refers to *horizontal* field of view, according to the [key](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH107-SW21). The discrepancy would be due to the fact that the values [calculated](https://sourceforge.net/p/exiftool/code/ci/master/tree/lib/Image/ExifTool/Exif.pm#l4160) by `exiftool` refer to *diagonal* [angle of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view).

As pointed out in comments, "field of view" would technically be defined as a *distance* across a plane at a given distance from the sensor. In practice, "field of view" is commonly used to mean "angle of view", as in both of your sources. Angle of view is generally given as diagonal, unless stated otherwise, since this is the angle needed for a lenses image circle to cover the entire sensor. Therefore, when asked for "angular field of view", this is probably what's being asked for, but if it's important you should confirm this.

Note that the values given by `exiftool` are based on the reported sensor dimensions and lens focal length, and may or may not be accurate enough for any given purpose. The documentation you linked to seems to imply that the use of OIS can slightly alter the actual FoV, for instance. For any critical purpose you could do some empirical testing, either by measuring a physical scene, or using software such as [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to stitch a 360-degree panorama (it will calculate this information about the provided images in the process).

Comment: if you add a link to documentation for exiftool that shows FOV is for the diagonal measure, i'll accept your answer.

Comment: The exiftool docs page on [composite tags](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Composite.html) is mysteriously silent on the matter of "Field Of View", hence the "probably" nature of my answer. The important point is that this tag is derived from other tags, and probably involves assumptions. My own assumption is that `exiftool` is giving a calculated [*angle of view*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view), that is, the angle needed to cover the entire sensor, corner to corner. If accuracy is important for your purposes, some empirical testing is probably in order.

Comment: Using the *diagonal* as the primary measure of a lens' angle of view has been the standard for at least a century before EXIF ever existed. In the absence of a description to the contrary, a single AoV value is always assumed to be measured diagonally. This diagonal measure also corresponds to measuring the diameter of the lens' usable imaging circle (assuming the lens is designed for the particular format size of the film or sensor in question).

Comment: Also note that apple's description as "field of view" (FoV) when expressing an angle of view (AoV) is incorrect. If the expressed value is an angle, it is an AoV and not an FoV. An FoV is expressed in a linear measure that is perpendicular to the optical axis at a specified distance from the camera/binoculars/telescope/etc. As in, "FoV = 176 feet @ 1,000 feet."

Comment: You can find the appropriate code that exiftool uses to make the Field of View calculations [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/exiftool/code/ci/master/tree/lib/Image/ExifTool/Exif.pm#l4160).  There is a note that it references [Field of View - Rectilinear and Fishye Lenses](http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/technical/field_of_view.html) on BobAtkins.com.

Comment: Further searching through the code, it appears that it calculates ScaleFactor35efl on the diagonal.  Those calculations can be found in the [CalcScaleFactor35efl subroutine](https://sourceforge.net/p/exiftool/code/ci/master/tree/lib/Image/ExifTool/Exif.pm#l4589).

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks for digging that up... as much as I love exiftool, the docs aren't as well maintained as they could be. :/

Comment: @MichaelClark While the use of FoV when meaning AoV may not be correct, it seems to be *very* common; I can't think of any cases I've seen of software wanting anything other than an angle when asking for "FoV".

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Probably due to an early software developer's ignorance of the proper usage of each term, similar to 'ppi' being described as 'dpi' in the EXIF standard.